# jQuery: How to count children within element with class

Tags: jquery

I have multiple 'div' elements with the same class 'column' and within each one I've got an unordered list 'ul' with class 'list' and elements 'li' with class 'item'.

The number of 'li.item' vary depends on different 'column'. 
How can I count the number of 'li.item' within a single 'column'?

I tried:

```
<div class="column">
<ul class="list">
<li class="item">item 1</li>
<li class="item">item 2</li>
<li class="item">item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
<ul class="list">
<li class="item">item 4</li>
<li class="item">item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
<ul class="list">
<li class="item">item 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0hj58xe/

I wolud like to have: 3 , 2 , 1 insted of 6,6,6  (each div treated separately).

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `.each()` to loop through columns

```js
$('.column').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).find('.item').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">item 1</li>
    <li class="item">item 2</li>
    <li class="item">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">item 4</li>
    <li class="item">item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is targeting all `ul` elements. You Need To iterate over the `ul` elements and then find child elements in it. You can use elements context `this` to target the current `ul` in `.each()` along with traversing selector to find elements and append count info in div:

```
$('.list').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var items = $this.find('.item').length;
  $this.closest('.column').append(items);
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/poxr7cdh/)**

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same answer as the others, just without 'find' and 'closest'.

```
$('.column').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$($this).append($('.list .item', $this).length);
});
```